# Thread[] seems to reset changes made with Manipulate[]

Tags: manipulate

Recently I have been working on group theory and I have found checking for associativity for specific Cayley tables to be rather tedious so I wrote a program to do it for me. Most of the time I would make the Cayley tables first and then run the program to check if it is associative. However, I recently decided to put it all together into one `Manipulate[]` to speed up my productivity. By doing so though, things got a little glitchy. The problem I am having is with creating the rules. I think I managed to narrowed it down to one line of code(?) and so below is my code *without* the actual function for checking associativity, only the part which seems to make the program to malfunction.

```
alphabet = "IABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

Manipulate[
aList = StringJoin[#] & /@Tuples[Table[StringTake[alphabet, {n}], {n, letters}], {2}]; 
bList = Table["I",{letters},{letters}]; 
rules = Thread[aList -> Flatten[bList]]; (*If I comment out this line everything works fine*)
Row[{Grid[
Prepend[Map[Flatten[#] &, 
  Transpose[{Table[StringTake[alphabet, {n}], {n, letters}], 
    Table[With[{n = n, m = m}, 
      PopupMenu[Dynamic[bList[[n, m]]], 
       Table[StringTake[alphabet, {o}], {o, letters}]]], {n, 
      letters}, {m, letters}]}]], 
 Prepend[Table[StringTake[alphabet, {n}], {n, letters}], ""]], 
Dividers -> {2 -> True, 2 -> True}], Spacer[50], 
Dynamic[bList]}], {letters, 1, 8, 1}]
```

When I run this program and set a value for a particular element in the grid; `bList` will update, but quickly switch back to it's initial state. However if I remove

```
rules = Thread[aList -> Flatten[bList]];
```

the value changes as it should. I tried placing `Dynamic[]` in various places without success. I'm not sure how to proceed, so any help on how to fix the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does using `RuleDelayed`

```
rules = Thread[aList :> Flatten[bList]]
```

work for what you need?

[image]

EDIT: Although changing `Rule` to `RuleDelayed` solves the issue of dynamic updating of `bList`,  `rules=Thread[aList :> Flatten[bList]]` does not produce the desired rule. Replacing this line with

```
 rules = (aList[[#]] :> Flatten[bList][[#]]) & /@ Range[Length[aList]];
```

produces the desired rule mapping elements of `aList` to elements of `bList`:

```
Manipulate[
aList = StringJoin[#] & /@ 
Tuples[Table[StringTake[alphabet, {n}], {n, letters}], {2}];
bList = Table["I", {letters}, {letters}];
rules = (aList[[#]] :> Flatten[bList][[#]]) & /@ Range[Length[aList]];
Column[{Grid[Prepend[Map[Flatten[#] &,
  Transpose[{Table[StringTake[alphabet, {n}], {n, letters}],
    Table[With[{n = n, m = m}, PopupMenu[Dynamic[bList[[n, m]]],
       Table[StringTake[alphabet, {o}], {o, letters}]]], {n, 
      letters}, {m, letters}]}]],
 Prepend[Table[StringTake[alphabet, {n}], {n, letters}], ""]], 
Dividers -> {2 -> True, 2 -> True}],
Spacer[50],
Column[{Dynamic[aList], Dynamic[bList // MatrixForm], 
 Dynamic["II" /. rules], Dynamic["AB" /. rules]}]}],
{letters, 1, 8, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Same answer as mine - only you provide the picture, too... (+1)

Comment: @Jens , yes ... and about 2 minutes before yours :)

Comment: Thanks. However the rules doesn't seem to work if I try the simple `("II"/.rules)`. Instead it returns `bList`.

Comment: @E.O., does ` Dynamic["II" /. rules]` produce what you need?

Comment: @kguler sorry, I meant `Dynamic["II"/.rules]` produces `bList` while `"II"/.rules` doesn't allow me to change any of the PopupMenus (i.e. neither seems to work).

Comment: @E.O., I added an alternative approach that uses `Map` and `RuleDelayed` combination instead of `Thread[...]`.

Comment: @kguler thanks! Worked perfectly!

Comment: @E.O. glad to hear that it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is for the `rule` to update all elements of `aList` when `bList` changes due to a change in `letters`. To achieve this, you have to make the assignment  into a `RuleDelayed`:

```
alphabet = "IABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

Manipulate[
 aList = StringJoin[#] & /@ 
   Tuples[Table[StringTake[alphabet, {n}], {n, letters}], {2}];
 bList = Table["I", {letters}, {letters}];
 rules = Thread[
   aList :> 
    Flatten[bList]]; (*If I comment out this line everything works fine*)
    Row[{Grid[
    Prepend[Map[Flatten[#] &, 
      Transpose[{Table[StringTake[alphabet, {n}], {n, letters}], 
        Table[With[{n = n, m = m}, 
          PopupMenu[Dynamic[bList[[n, m]]], 
           Table[StringTake[alphabet, {o}], {o, letters}]]], {n, 
          letters}, {m, letters}]}]], 
     Prepend[Table[StringTake[alphabet, {n}], {n, letters}], ""]], 
    Dividers -> {2 -> True, 2 -> True}], Spacer[50], 
   Dynamic[bList]}], {letters, 1, 8, 1}]
```

The only change with respect to your original code is that I defined

```
rules = Thread[aList :> Flatten[bList]]
```

where `:>` is `RuleDelayed`.